# How big a share needs to be provisioned for a File Share Witness

Tags: windows-cluster

We're creating a new Windows Cluster. All 3 nodes are Windows 2012 R2. We want to utilize a File Share Witness. How much space needs to be provisioned for the witness?

The test cluster we've created is only using 1KB of space. Is that all it will ever use, or do we need to provision a bigger space when we go live?

===Update===

Is there a Microsoft article specifying the minimum requirements for a FSW?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file share should only be hosting two files, which are created automatically; one text file to verify the correct Share and NTFS permissions to the share and one log file. In my Windows Server 2012 R2 failover cluster the verification file is 0KB and the log file is 1KB. So, the host that is hosting the file share witness doesn't need to have a very large drive. The fileshare witness doesn't hold any other data other than the two files I described. The Microsoft Failover Clustering and Network Load Balancing Team recommends having 5MB of available disk space per cluster that the FSW will be provisioned for.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/clustering/archive/2014/03/31/10512457.aspx